# Flash Template recommendations?

Tags: flash, video

I'm new to Flash but want to create a nice video for a product. It takes a long time to make a nice looking presentation , and I'm hoping for a jump start.

Are there any good templates which are free on the internet where I can quickly change the text in ,for example, to make my video?

I've tried looking in google, and there are too many websites, many of which look gimmicky. Any recommendations?

(A video like this one - http://flowplayer.org/tools/flashembed.html - would be amazing!)

Answer (score 1):

That is a very slick video indeed - but it is just that a video. More than likely it was created with Adobe After Effects and then just exported to an FLV. After that it's just a video player written in Flash.

So while I can not give a recommendation for a flash template, it doesn't sound like Flash is actually the best choice for what you want anyways - start looking at After Effects and related video tools.